# Storing multiple files as variable based on match

Tags: bash, variables

is there a way to do a search of a user's current working directory for all files beginning with `backup_file` and then storing all the data within those files as a variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: @Kind Stranger Not really. I understand how to store data from files into a variable. However, I have no clue how to store all files starting with a match (e.g. backup_file) into one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? `cat` will fetch the contents of given file(s). `.` is current directory.

```sh
all_data="$(cat ./backup_file*)"
```